# Pyspark levenshtein Join stuck on the same stage

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, levenshtein-distance, fuzzywuzzy

I want to perform a join based on Levenshtein distance.

I have 2 dataframes:

- **Data** : small dataframe with  130K rows.
- **Siren**: large dataframe, which represents the  table [stockunitelegale](https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/r/260b1c83-1fe0-4d8d-9712-4504a14f2687)  of the database [SIREN](https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/base-sirene-des-entreprises-et-de-leurs-etablissements-siren-siret/) , with 20M rows.

I tried to broadcast the small dataframe and perform the join with the large dataset.
Spark Job is always stuck on the last three tasks of the join...

```
data=broadcast(data)
df=siren.join(spk, 1-(fn.levenshtein(data["description_nom"], 
                               siren["denominationUniteLegale"])/ fn.greatest(fn.length(data["description_nom"]),
                                                                           fn.length(siren["denominationUniteLegale"])))>0.7)
df.write.csv("join_siren.csv")
```

I tried also to increase the number of executors, the number of cores and the memory allocated , but I had the same behavior in terms of processing.

```
--num-executors 20 --conf "spark.executor.memory=12g" --conf "spark.executor.cores=15" --conf "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=1000" --conf "spark.default.parallelism=1000" --conf "spark.driver.maxResultSize=8g" --conf "spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=20485760" --conf "spark.network.timeout=10000000"
```

Do you have any solutions please for this kind of problem ?

Comment: Try it in steps, ignore broadcasting, just first join the tables `joined_df =df1.join(df2,levenshtein(df1['description'], df2['description']))` and save it. Then in a new script perform the other operations using clever map reduction or a UDF.

Comment: @Leo103 Thank you for your reply. We cannot make a join with levenstein without putting a condition.

Answer (score 0):

Even though one of your dataframe is small, what you are essentially doing is a cartesian product with this join. Because in order for spark to know which row combination satisfy your condition it has to first create every single combination of rows from the left and the right dataframe of the join. This means 130k times 20m which would be two trillion six hundred billion rows. That's quite big.

What I would suggest is to first join on some other condition which would reduce the search space of your fuzzy name matching. For example you could use something like a postcode. Some other example could be to split your columns `description_nom` and `denominationUniteLegale` on space and join on any token matching. And then filter on

```py
    1-(fn.levenshtein(data["description_nom"], 
                                   siren["denominationUniteLegale"])/ fn.greatest(fn.length(data["description_nom"]),
                                                                               fn.length(siren["denominationUniteLegale"])))>0.7
```

This will depend on what you have available in your dataframes. You will have to experiment a bit what works well. For example with the postcode suggestion you could do this:

```py
df=siren.join(data, data["postcode"]==siren["codePostalEtablissement"])
df=df.filter(1-(fn.levenshtein(data["description_nom"], 
                               siren["denominationUniteLegale"])/ fn.greatest(fn.length(data["description_nom"]),
                                                                               fn.length(siren["denominationUniteLegale"])))>0.7)
df.write.csv("join_siren.csv")
```

Of course this is just an example and you could combine different conditions in the join such as join on postcode or streetName or name token matching. But you still have to check that it would not generate too many rows like you had with the cartesianJoin. For that you have to check for any of your condition the worst case. For example for the postcode, if you count the number of rows in `data` and `siren` grouped by postcode, what is the largest combination. Assuming you have a column called `postcode` in `data`, you could get this information as follows:

```py
dataPostcodeCount = data.groupBy('postcode').count()
sirenPostcodeCount = siren.groupBy('codePostalEtablissement').count()
postCodeCounts = dataPostcodeCount \
    .join(sirenPostcodeCount, data['postcode'] == siren['codePostalEtablissement']) \
    .select('postcode', (data['count']*siren['count']).alias('count'))
postCodeCounts.sortBy(postCodeCounts['count'].desc()).show()
```